# Is it possible to have a nested where and and clause in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've tried search for this and I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology, but is it possible to have a nested WHERE AND clause?:

```
select id from tabel_1 where first_name = 'Jay' and last_name = 'McDonald' and (age = 18 and hair_colour = black)
```

So the nested AND would "**and (age != 18 and hair_colour != black)**" so you could have:

first_name = 'Jay' evaluate to true

last_name = 'McDonald' evaluate to true

(age = 18 and hair_colour = black) only evaluate to true if both age and hair_colour are true

With the idea that only ids with both 18 and black are exclude, but not ids with just black or just 18

Comment: Why not just try yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (age = 18 and hair_colour = black) only evaluate to true if both age and hair_colour are true

This already happens. You don't even need the parentheses.

> only ids with both 18 and black are exclude, but not ids with just black or just 18

You want something more like this:

```
AND NOT (age = 18 and hair_colour = 'black')
```

But you should also look at [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which allows us to rewrite it like this:

```
AND (age != 18 OR hair_colour != 'black')
```

But let's say you also want to require one of those to be TRUE: that is, we want an exclusive OR (XOR):

```
AND (age  = 18 OR hair_colour  = 'black')
AND (age != 18 OR hair_colour != 'black')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
from tabel_1 
where first_name = 'Jay' 
and last_name = 'McDonald' 
and (
  age = 18 OR 
  hair_colour = black
)
```